# Panel docking within a form. Make two panels "stick" on resize

Tags: c#, forms

I have two panels on a custom control that I am creating. One is docked on the left of the control and the other is docked on the right.

[image]

Currently Panel 1 and 2 will "pull apart" when re-sizing the control leaving a large hole in the middle showing nothing but the controls background.

Is there a way to make Panel 2 stay at a fixed size and dock on the right.

While panel 1 stays docked on the left, but also resizeable. Though, I would like to make it so that the panel "sticks" to Panel 2, so that no gap between the two is ever produced because Panel 1 will stretch to fill it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the two `Panel` controls and replace them with a `SplitContainer`.

Set `FixedPanel = Panel2`, which will cause the right panel to stay the same size when you resize the user control (the left panel will grow and shrink). The panels will still be resizable via a vertical divider between the two panels, and you won't have a gap in the middle.

By default, when you add the `SplitContainer`, it should be set to `Dock = Fill` so it fills the entire user control.

In the following images, you can see that when resizing the container, the right panel remains fixed width. In the last image, the panel width has been programmatically changed.

[image]

Comment: Ehhh. Pretty good. I think I'll use it. A few issues, but I think I can work them out.

Comment: Hehe, just found it and deleted my comment, didn't think you'd see it.